# Comparing YUI2 and YUI3

Tags: upgrade, yui

I was using YUI 2.9 version before and now to upgrade it to YUI 3.18.1 what are the benefits that I will be getting from it. From where can I get those things which got improvised with YUI up-gradation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them are projects in active development, you would be switching from on dead-end to another.  [GitHub](https://github.com/yui/yui3) shows the last change to its repository dated 3 years ago.

The changes to your code when migrating are substantial. There is no easy upgrade. There are no major gains in doing an upgrade. Not all YUI2 components are available in YUI3. The rewrite would be so extensive that you might as well use your time rewriting the full app to use some other technology.

Comment: So is it better me to upgrade to AngularJS than to YUI3.18 with all time and efficiency matters?

Comment: There are several technologies you can use, Angular amongst them.  Any that is actively supported (providing regular fixes and improvements) and with a thriving community (for mutual support) is better than an inactive one.